# Parse String into DOM, ng-click dont work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to create n Buttons in "#text", wich do button() on ng-click. When i call the "loadButtons(n)" function, the buttons are showen, but on click nothings happen...
The test button works perfectly...
I think it has to do with the parsing from string to DOM, but I dont know how to do it better ... :(

.html

```
<div id="test">
   <button class="button button-full button-light" ng-click="button();">Test</button>
</div>

<div id="text"></div>
```

.js

```
$scope.button = function () {
    console.log("BUTTON");
};

//Load n buttons in #text
$scope.loadButtons = function (n) {
    var content = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        content = content.concat('<button class="button button-full button-light"' 
        +'ng-click="button();">' + i + '</button>');
    }
    $('#text').html(content);
}
```

Comment: you should rather use `ng-repeat` for this... it will add buttons to dom as many times as you like

Comment: use angular to create dom from your data model, don't use jQuery for this

Comment: You can't inject html containing angular directives without using `$compile`. There are much simpler ways to do this using angular best practices

Comment: Thanks, Im new to angular...I think I try it with ng-repeat :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ng-repeat directive as follows

```
<div id="test">
   <button 
       class="button button-full button-light" 
       ng-repeat="i in getNumber(maxButtons) track by $index"
       ng-click="testButton(i)"
       >
       {{i}}
   </button>
</div>
```

In your controller, you can have following code:

```
    $scope.maxButtons= 10;
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
       return new Array(num);   
    }
    $scope.testButton = function(val){
       console.log(val);
    }
```

**Start thinking in Angular way :)**